# Convert array of strings into object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an array that I am trying to display using ng-grid like so:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G33IlPCNAdh1jmNTtVNO?p=preview

I understand that ng-grid cannot have the `field` portion as an array--it requires a JSON object. I also understand that, in reference to my plunkr above, if you uncomment out `$scope.test2` and replace all instances of `$scope.test` with `$scope.test2`, the information would display all the data inside `$scope.test2` as desired, as opposed to the `undefined` messages I am getting in the current state of the plunkr.

How would I change my `$scope.test` to look something like `$scope.test2` programatically? I just want to change the format of the array to look like `$scope.test2` just for this `ng-grid`. Is it possible? If anyone could help that would be great.

Edit:

Basically I want to change

```
$scope.test = ['blah', 'blah2'];
```

to looking like

```
$scope.test2 = [{name:['blah', 'blah2']}]; //name can be changed to anything
//name just has to specify the name of the array inside this object.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your code here, as links die, and users shouldn't have to go to a external site to view the code. Sites like plnkr,jsfiddle,etc are used for live demos not as a source reference

Comment: @PatrickEvans I added relevant parts of my code to the question. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is that you need an array of objects that represent one row each, meaning you want test to look something like this:

```
$scope.test = [
  { test: 'blah' },
  { test: 'blah2' }
];
```

To do that programmatically, you could do something like this:

```
$scope.test = [ 'blah', 'blah2' ];
$scope.testObjects = [];
$scope.test.forEach( function( val ){
  $scope.testObjects.push( { test: val } );
});
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'testObjects',
  columnDefs: [
    {field: 'test', displayName: 'Test'},
  ]
};
```

which gets rid of your need for a filter.  See [my revised plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhIg1jUxY8kNbyKDwlrN?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$scope.test2 = [{name: $scope.test}];
```

`$scope.test` is an object reference, so anything changed in `$scope.test` will also be reflected in `$scope.test2[0].name`